# Deactivate middle mouse button or make middle-click left click?

Tags: gnome, touchpad

I have an Asus VivoBook and the touch pad has no buttons, but just areas that functions as buttons. My main problem is that if I left click just a millimeter too far to the right, it is considered a middle-click, which in Firefox is used to instantly nuke a tab instead of focusing it. It's driving me nuts and I would like to either deactivate it so that I can have a safe zone or make middle-button be interpreted as left-button.

I'm using Ubuntu with Gnome running in a Wayland session. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you enable middle-click emulation, then the middle-button will be disabled and you'll have to click left and right at the same time if you want to use the middle-button. For me, this was a complete solution and it can be done by setting the configuration variable `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation true`